# How to store embeds_many / embedded_in in mongoid as a Hash instead of Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, associations, mongoid

As I'm building a new API for an existing legacy system, I'm trying to figure out how to model a relationship in a way that makes sense for the ODM but maintain the same storage structure that is already existing.

The current structure is stored as:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  name: String,
  relationship_ids: {
    "5c06a0eb350e6ef20d1486b9" : {
        "id" : "5c06a0eb350e6ef20d1486b9", 
        "type" : "package"
    },
    "5ba105bf350e6e3f6ef97532" : {
        "id" : "5ba105bf350e6e3f6ef97532", 
        "type" : "something"
    }
 }
}
```

And I'd like to model the object as if it's its own Model in Rails.
I thought maybe there was a way to do this but I don't see it anywhere.

I'm guessing I need some sort of serialize / deserialize adapter or override it specifically at the `embedded_in do` / `embeds_many do` area... but not sure.

UPDATE:

I'm guessing it has something to do with this overriding methods on this somehow:
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/7.0/api/Mongoid/Association/Embedded/EmbedsMany/Proxy.html

But I am somewhat new to this and don't have a clue where the best place to put this type of override.

Anybody else have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use polymorphic associations (see the [docs](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) "Polymorphism"):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :photos, as: :photographic
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :photographic, polymorphic: true
end

class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :photographic, polymorphic: true
end
```

Polymorphic relations store both id and class name of the associated document.

Comment: Thanks for this.  If I recall, `embeds_many` stores them as an array.  I'm specifically needing them in the format in the original post since its a part of a legacy system. :-/